# .htaccess Mod Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a .htaccess mod rewrite for an "infinite" amount of values.  I mean 10 may be a good max number, but if I wish to increase then I would like for the script to be able to as well.

For instance:

```
From: http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=test
To:   http://www.domain.com/test

From: http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=test&act=blah
To:   http://www.domain.com/test/blah

From: http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=test&act=blah&id=6
To:   http://www.domain.com/test/blah/6
```

All pages will have at least the "page" field, but not all my have extras and the extras may all be different names.  However, **I do not care about the field names.**  If it just redirects to: index.php?1=test&2=blah&3=6 then that would be the best.

I was thinking of possibly redirecting to something like below internally.

```
From: http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=test/blah
To:   http://www.domain.com/test/blah
```

*I am sorry if my post is a little confusing; I have tried to edit it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you need but here is something that will give you idea on how to write recursive rules in mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ $3?$1=$2 [N,QSA,DPI]
RewriteRule ^(/[^/]+|[^/]+/|/?)$ /index.php [L,QSA,DPI]
```

This redirects a URI of `/hello/1/test/2/blah/3/foo/4` to `index.php?foo=4&blah=3&test=2&hello=1`.

#### Update Based on OP's comments:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ $3?$2 [N,QSA,DPI]
RewriteRule ^(/[^/]+|[^/]+/|/?)$ /index.php [L,QSA,DPI]
```

This redirects a URI of `/1/hello/2/test/3/blah/4/foo` to `/index.php?foo&blah&test&hello`.

Comment: I do not want the numbers in the URL though.  I want the URL to look just like that, but without the numbers.

Comment: Please re-read my original post.  I am looking for /hello/test/blah/foo/  to redirect to index.php?1=hello&2=test&3=blah&4=foo.  You have it backwards.

Comment: @Flipper: mod_rewrite is not really programming code and you cannot really increment a counter in it (at least I don't know). If you have 1, 2, 3, 4 in original URI then of course it can be used in query string.

Comment: Makes sense.  I have just re-routed everything to index.php?something=  and then used PHP to split it all.  But thanks anyway.  Solved my question: there is no way to do it.